# How do I compare user integer input to values in dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm working on a vending machine program and my code skips straight to the else statement instead of taking the user input and comparing it to the ID number in the list.

Here's the list and code:
`

```
itemstock = [

    {
        "idnum": 0,
        "name": 'Water',
        "price": 12,
    },
    {
        "idnum": 1,
        "name": 'Soda',
        "price": 14,
    },
    {
        "idnum": 2,
        "name": 'Juice',
        "price": 13,
    },
    ]
```

```
choice = int(input("Now, choose an item ID from the Menu and enter the ID: "))
for i in itemstock:
    if choice in ["idnum"]:
        print("You have chosen item", choice)
    else:
        print("This is not a valid ID.")
        break
```

`

I had hoped for if I had input the number 2, it would display what the user chose along with some text but it skips straight to the else statement. I've tried looking online but I may be doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice in ["idnum"]
```

That is just a list containing the text "idnum".  You want `i["idnum"]` instead:

```
for i in itemstock:
    if i["idnum"] == choice:
        print("You have chosen item", choice)
        break
else:
    print("This is not a valid ID.")
```

I also moved the `else` block out one level, so it is paired with the `for` loop, not the `if` statement.  When a `for` loop iterates all the way to the end, the `else` block is executed (if it has one).